# Silverlight 4 RIA does not return anything using DomainContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Just learning Silverlight 4/RIA and i 'm stuck in a weird problem:
setup an ASP.NET MVC project as the project hosting the Domain service. In this i tried to get data from the Domain Service which worked fine (i'm using a repository which gets resolved using Windsor Castle).

Now i tried to setup a SL4 project. I though i do it the MVVM-way, so i decided to setup a ViewModel Class with the following code:

```
public class ViewModel
{
        OrganizationDomainContext dsCtxt = new OrganizationDomainContext();

        public ViewModel()
        {
           EntityQuery<Culture> query = from cu in dsCtxt.GetAllCulturesQuery()
                                         select cu;
            LoadOperation<Culture> lo = dsCtxt.Load(query);

        }

}
```

The crazy thing about this is .. it doesn't return anything!!!
What am i missing here?

**EDIT:**
I was not very clear about this issue: i 'm using Windsor Castle to do IoC stuff. Using Fiddler i see that the application tries to resolve something that looks like the name of the Silverlight application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the aforementioned Silverlight application is actually the service i'm using to get data. I solved this ignoring routing issues to this service (in RegisterRoutes() ) like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allsvc}", new { allsvc = @".*\.svc(/.*)?" });
```